# Friction force in rolling motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, terminology, friction

In rolling without slipping motion we know that the friction acting is static friction and so we treat it as an unknown while solving equations of dynamics.

**Question: Is the [static friction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friction#Static_friction) during pure rolling the same as [rolling friction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_resistance)?**

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/146039/392

Answer (score 2):

Rolling friction result from for example small changes in the surface or in the wheel material (the rubber in a tire).

The surface is not perfectly flat and rigid so there will be some small forces trying to stop the rotating motion:

[image]
<sub>(source: [davidson.edu](http://www.phy.davidson.edu/fachome/dmb/PY430/Friction/actroll.gif))</sub>

On the contrary, the static friction is not trying to stop the rotation of the wheel.

Static and rolling friction are different things.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Rolling friction is the fraction of resistive force to normal load. It is a fudge factor, lumping all rolling related resistances into one dimensionless value. This applies to rolling only.

Static friction is a measurable quantity relating to the maximum resistance an interface provides before sliding occurs. This applies to sticking only.